# Cannot submit POST form using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms, post

I have the following form:

```
<form id="form1" class="form1" action="https://www.someexternalsite.com/api/some/route?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
    <input type=hidden id="pid" name="pid" value="00NJAHSJASASAS">
    <label for="symbol">Symbol</label><input id="symbol" name="00NALKSJSKA" maxlength="10" size="20" type="text" />
    <input type="button" name="submitThis" id="qwSubmit" class="submitForm1Button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My js to hook onclick event handling:

```
$(function () {
    $("#qwSubmit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            validateForm(); // this includes some ajax requests for some parts of the validation
        } catch (e) {
            showValidationError(e);
            return;
        }

        $("#form1").submit();
    });

    $("#form1").keypress(function (event) {
        if (window.event) event = window.event;
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
            $("#qwSubmit").click();
        }
    });
});
```

What am I missing or doing wrong that's preventing the submission?

Edit:

There are no js errors. When I click submit, it just kinda sits there; I do see it firing off the ajaxs to validate certain fields.

Edit:

I've also tried:

```
button.submit(function(er) {e.prevent... return true});
```

Comment: Is `showValidationError()` doing anything?

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors?

Comment: just change innerHTML of soem div

Comment: why not put all of your Submit code in a separate function and call that in your click and keypress events?

Comment: Instead of trying to catch all possible ways of submitting a form, why don't you listen to [`submit`](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) event instead?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that it simply never returns to the inline function.

I suggest changing the process flow so that the validation function submits the form on success.

```
$(function () {
    function validateForm() {
        // validation logic

        // Submit form
        $("#form1").submit();
    }

    $("#qwSubmit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            validateForm(); // this includes some ajax requests for some parts of the validation
        } catch (e) {
            showValidationError(e);
            return;
        }
    });

    $("#form1").keypress(function (event) {
        if (window.event) event = window.event;
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
            $("#qwSubmit").click();
        }
    });
});
```